# Counting distinct numbers with built-in functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array with multiple columns containing integers ranging from 1 to 99. I am looking to get the count of distinct numbers in this array. Seems like a relatively easy task but I could not come up with a solution using built-in Excel functions. I wrote a user-defined function that does the trick though.

Examples:
3 3 1 => 2 distinct numbers (1, 3)
2 2 2 => 1 distinct number
5 4 3 => 3 distinct numbers

Here the user-defined function. Probably a bit too complicated with 3 loops but it works.

```
' Select a range of cells, 1 row and multiple columns.
Function disnr(sel As Range) As Byte
Dim i     As Byte
Dim col   As Byte
Dim max   As Byte
Dim val   As Byte
Dim arr() As Variant

col = sel.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To col                             ' Loop1: get max value
   If sel(1, i) > max Then max = sel(1, i)
Next i
ReDim arr(1 To max)

For i = 1 To col                             ' Loop2: count occurences
   val = sel(1, i)
   arr(val) = arr(val) + 1
Next i

For i = 1 To max                             ' Loop3: count distinct numbers
   If arr(i) > 0 Then disnr = disnr + 1
Next i
End Function
```

Comment: `=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(A1:C1,A1:C1))` for example.

Comment: This is good - more concise than my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing this:

[image]

unique() to get rid of the duplicates

and count to get the total.

To save you typing:

```
COUNT(UNIQUE(A1:C1,TRUE,FALSE))
```

based on my layout.

Comment: Great solution but I only have Excel 2019 which does not have the UNIQUE() function.

Comment: Then that would be crucial information to put into your question. But you do have the 'Remove duplicates" button...

Answer (score 3):

For older Excel-versions: Collect all values in a dictionary. The size of the dictionary gives you the number of unique values.

```
Function countUnique(r As Range) As Long
    Dim dict As New Dictionary, cell As Range
    For Each cell In r
        ' If you ever want to know how many occurrences of a value there are
        dict(cell.Value) = dict(cell.Value) + 1
    Next
    countUnique = dict.Count
End Function
```

As I hate late binding: You need to add a reference to the Scripting.Runtime (or change the code to late binding). And drawback: Doesn't work on MacOS

**Update**: Code simplified thanks to FaneDurus hint.

Answer (score 1):

On older versions of Excel you can use

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(A1:C1,A1:C1)>0))
```

(array-entered) or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(A1:C1,A1:C1)>0))
```

[image]